Отсутствует пинг между клиентами Wireguard
Мне понадобилось соединить 3 VPS вместе, на каждый из них установил Wireguard. В /etc/sysctl.conf раскоментировал строку net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 на всех VPS. Отключил фаервол. Сделал настройку как приведено ниже, после чего начал проверять пинг между серверами, и вот какие результаты получил:
server  -> client1 - работает
server  -> client2 - работает
client1 -> server  - работает
client1 -> client2 - работает
client2 -> server  - работает
client2 -> client1 - НЕ работает

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?
** SERVER **

[Interface]
Address = 10.10.0.1/32
ListenPort = 51820
Privatekey = QLatdWns51wyLF/QAFVmJvCkoQJiFKSzboWEg8Hl5HE=

[Peer]
Publickey = ieinVpryoW/PekK1InFYfkswoD7CYzffjDCalJevT3o=
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.2/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

[Peer]
Publickey = PrQ3AFNptWRpvAP9NE6mOF6RSlObqITaJV1aeGWXvlI=
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.3/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

------------------------------
** CLIENT 1 **

[Interface]
Address = 10.10.0.2/32
ListenPort = 51820
Privatekey = cC5LAZareaGbSKlEiy69+T2qbTXBktF5X2vbTD3gZXM=

[Peer]
Publickey = d7CHugwcIPvTIBSM1XVJ3eypKnb6C3NFzn3nyuVPWS0=
Endpoint = 95.163.223.67:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.1/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25

------------------------------
** CLIENT 2 **

[Interface]
Address = 10.10.0.3/32
ListenPort = 51820
Privatekey = 4LW6f/r29yL3gSqAbrFrjfyuKzdm8UeS90B1QcnCDVQ=

[Peer]
Publickey = d7CHugwcIPvTIBSM1XVJ3eypKnb6C3NFzn3nyuVPWS0=
Endpoint = 95.163.223.67:51820
AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.1/32
PersistentKeepalive = 25


AllowedIPs = 10.10.0.1/32 -ip другого клиента в пролете

Вы имеете ввиду то что нужно добавить в CLIENT 1 и CLIENT 2 [Peer]ы соответствующие CLIENT 1 -> CLIENT 2 а в CLIENT 2 -> CLIENT 1?
